# How to get current user to display profile page in React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create a profile page in my React app. The user data is in the state but I want to load the data from the API as I load the page.

I've tried tyo fetch the data with `this.props.getUser(this.props.auth._id)` in the `Constructor` or in `ComponentDidMount`, but it did not load.
The data does comes in through `componentWillReceiveProps`, but it does not load on the first page load. Although, if I refresh the page, the data comes in.

This is part of my `profile.js`:

```
class Profile extends Component {

  state = {
    _id: '',
    name: '',
    email: '',
    username: '',
    errors: {}
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadCurrentUser();
  }

  loadCurrentUser = () => {
    this.setState(this.props.getUser(this.props.auth._id));
  };

  // https://hackernoon.com/replacing-componentwillreceiveprops-with-getderivedstatefromprops-c3956f7ce607
  UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, nextState) {
    console.log("received")
    const { name, email, username } = nextProps.auth;
    this.setState({ name, email, username });
  }


// ...
// Some other code
// ...

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getUser, logOut })(Profile);
```

My question is: How to load the page with the data I get from the API presented in the form fields?

Thank you

---

**EDITED**

I have edited my componentDidMount to use promises, but I still can not get it right. Now, My store gets the states right, but my component still does not get updated.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getUser(this.props.auth.user)
      .then(user => this.setState({ name: user.name, email: user.email, username: user.username }))
  }
```

If I add a simple console.log, I still can not get the return from my query (getUser). This console.log is undefined.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getUser(this.props.auth.user)
      .then(user => console.log(user));
  }
```

---

This is my getUser (src/actions/userActions.js):

```
export const getUser = _id => async dispatch => {
  const res = await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_USERS_API}/api/v1/users/${_id}`);
  dispatch({
    type: GET_USER,
    payload: res.data.data
  });
};
```

Comment: "component still does not get updated", can you show a few lines of how you bind your data in the component to the state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getUser` action does not have return value. Instead, it updates the user data inside the redux store. So you shouldn't reply on the return value and set state from it.

Instead, dispatch the `getUser` action on page load so that the user data is updated and always access the data from the store (through `this.props.auth`). If there is an updated version of the user data, React handles the page re-render automatically:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getUser(this.props.auth.user);
}
```

If for some reason, you need the user data to be saved in state (for example, you have a form on page where user can update username/password), then use [`getDerivedStateFromProps` method](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops):

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    // return an object to update the state.
    return props.auth;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Claire. Now, I'm sorry if this is too basic, but I still could not get it, Look, I edited my question with my changes. Why is it still not loading?

Comment: So... I figured that if I use (`.then(u => this.setState(this.props.user));`) it works. My question, now is: Isn't the "u" here the output of my getUser? Why is it undefined even when I use "then"?

Comment: @brauliopf Could you share the details of the `getUser` function? My guess is something is not correct there. When you use `this.setState(this.props.user))`, you are actually not using the return value of the previous `getUser` call (`u` as you mentioned).

Comment: I've added my getUser function to the original post.

Comment: I've found it @Claire. I'm sorry. My backend API had a few login endpoints for different scenarios. The scenario that logs the user from a token in the localStorage returns a ".user" prop but the end points for registration and login does not.
I learned that I must be more careful organizing my API.